# Photos Gallery - Database Design model

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a gallery using php and mysql.

I'm uploading the original file for save keeping and storing it on the file system outside the root. The original file can be of type .tiff, .jpg or .png

I'm creating 3 different sizes on the fly using imageMagick. The thumbnails can only be of type jpg or png, never tiff. If the original file is a tif, I convert the thumbnails to a jpg type. If the file is a jpg or a png, I leave the image type as is.

The thumbnails are store on the file system using a sub-directories scheme to avoid having too many files.

I've tested all and works perfectly.

Now, I want to store the info in a database table to link the image. But, I'm 'struggling' with the database model to use. I have many on mind and have doubts which one is the most simple and optimal for my model.

This is the one I came up with; I'm looking for feedback on how to improve it. Thanks.

```
image (image_id, title, caption, filename, thumb_width, thumb_height, uploaded_date)
```

Something simple, not to complicated.

For the purpose of this post, let's say I upload a tiff image. I keep the original tiff outside the root, create 3 thumbnails of type jpg and store the info in the db like so:

```
image_id    title  caption   filename       thumb_width  thumb_height  uploaded_date
1           title  caption   34569.567.tif  100          89            2014-12-12
```

When displaying the thumbnails on PHP, I use the table attribute 'filename', extract the name without the extension and add the extension .jpg. If it's already a .jpg or .png, i leave it as is.

Should I add one attribute in the table to store the original filename and and another attribute to store the converted filename.
Should i split the filename attribute into 3 attributes: filename(only the name without the extension), original_extension and thumbnail_extension.

Looking for feedback, thanks

Comment: I suggest keep thumb_image name in another column in the DB. It will consume additional little amount of capacity, but eliminate the several conditional lines (PHP) of process.

Comment: If your users need to download the original file, with it's original name, then you have to store the original name as-well. also why not store the thumbnail filename? since they may stores with two different extensions then you have to store them extension anyway, so store the whole name on one column. in this way, as @Sadee mentioned, you may consume a little more space for db, but you do not have to process the name every time you want to create a link for the thumbnail.